# Prepare command line arguments in a variable

Tags: bash

I need to generate some images using ImageMagick. For this reason I prepare draw operation in variable before actually calling `convert`, which looks like this

```
convert -size 160x160 xc:skyblue \
-fill 'rgb(200, 176, 104)' \
$draw_operations \
$0.png
```

**$draw_operations** contains lines, like these

```
-draw 'point 30,50' \
-draw 'point 31,50'
```

This call to `convert` always results in

```
non-conforming drawing primitive definition `point` ...
unable to open image `'30,50'' ...
...
```

If I use **$draw_operations**  with double quotes (which is required, if it contains multiple lines) the error is

```
unrecognized option `-draw 'point 30,50' '
```

Finally if I simply put `-draw 'point 30,50'` as is, there is no error. So it's not related to ImageMagick, but rather to the way bash substitute variables.

Comment: Try typing `set | cat -vet` to see all the contents of your variables with linefeeds and everything expanded so you can see what your variable actually contains.

Comment: Thanks for accepting but Gordon's answer is much better, You might want to accept it instead of mine.

Comment: thumbs up for objectiveness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [BashFAQ 50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). The problem is that the shell parses quotes and escapes before it expands variables, so putting quotes in a variable's value doesn't work -- by the time the quotes "are there", it's too late for them to do any good.

In this case, it looks to me like the best solution would be to store the arguments in an array, and then use `"${array[@]}"` (including the double-quotes) to add them to the command. Something like this:

```
draw_operations=(-draw 'point 30,50' -draw 'point 31,50')
# Note that this creates an array with 4 elements, "-draw", "point 30,50",  "-draw", and "point 31,50"

convert -size 160x160 xc:skyblue \
    -fill 'rgb(200, 176, 104)' \
    "${draw_operations[@]}" \
    "$0.png"
```

You can also build the array incrementally, like this:

```
draw_operations=()    # Start with an empty array
draw_operations+=(-draw 'point 30,50')    # Add two elements
draw_operations+=(-draw 'point 31,50')    # Add two more elements
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval` instead. That should interpret the spaces and quoting correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
draw_operations="-draw 'point 30,50' \
 -draw 'point 31,50'"

eval "convert -size 160x160 xc:skyblue \
-fill 'rgb(200, 176, 104)' \
"$draw_operations" \
    "$0".png"
```

By the way, a useful debugging trick is to add `set -x` at the beginning of your script. That will show you what commands are executed and how.

---

Note that, as @GordonDavisson [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047688/prepare-command-line-arguments-in-a-variable#comment50135205_31048398) in the comments, `eval` is dangerous and will execute arbitrary code if, for example, your file name contains shell meta characters. I recommend you use [his approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056969/1081936) below which is both more elegant and safer.

Comment: `eval` is dangerous if you aren't very very careful. In this case, for example, it'll run into trouble if the filename happens to contain any shell metacharacters (and in some cases, can actually wind up executing part of the filename as a shell command itself!). It's much better to use arrays for this sort of thing.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I quite agree but couldn't find a way to avoid it. I tried the approach you show in your answer but was creating an array with two elements, not 4. So `"-draw 'point 30,50'"` was a single element. That still ran afoul of word splitting though. I hadn't considered separating the commands as you do. That makes a lot of sense, thanks.